# How to set static labels for ng2-charts bar charts?

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts. I have an array of data. I am printing day values in x-axis and marks in the y-axis. Problem is, if I have data only for Tue and Wednesday then it's showing only two but I want like static x-axis (Sun-Sat). As shown below

What I currently have:

[image: Screenshot of 2 bars (a blue on Monday and a yellow on Tuesday) on a bar chart]

What I want to get:

[image: Screenshot of 2 bars (a blue on Tuesday and a yellow on Wednesday) on a bar chart]

**HTML**

```html
<div style="display: block" *ngIf="barChartData">
  <canvas baseChart width="400" height="180" style="margin-left:5%;margin- 
top: 5%;" [datasets]="barChartData"
[labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" 
[legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType"
(chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" [colors]="chartColors" 
(chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
</div>
```

**TS**

```ts
this.barChartLabels = this.days; //Have week days like[tue,wed]
setTimeout(() => {
 this.barChartData = [
   { data: this.marks },
 ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the solution please update your code like below.

**HTML**

```
 <div>
        <div style="display: block">
           <canvas baseChart
                [datasets]="barChartData"
                [labels]="barChartLabels"
                [options]="barChartOptions"
                [legend]="barChartLegend"
                [chartType]="barChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
         </div>
      <button (click)="randomize()">Update</button>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent {

    public barChartOptions:any = {
        scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        responsive: true
    };
  public barChartLabels:string[] = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
  public barChartType:string = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend:boolean = true;

  public barChartData:any[] = [
    {data: [0, 0, 80, 81, 0, 0, 0], label: 'Graph 1'},
  ]
}
```

**Here [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example-nwd56c?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**